# Text cannot be parsed to a Duration in java8

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a text to duration as follow:

```
  final Duration duration = TimeUtil.parseDuration("1.0:00:00");
```

But I get the following error,

```
Text cannot be parsed to a Duration
```

so can anyone tells me where my problem is?

Comment: Where did you import `TimeUtil` from? It's not in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/allclasses-noframe.html

Comment: Please specify from what library you got `TimeUtil` from.

Comment: OOPPPPS sorry yes you are right I am working on a system which is totally new to me, apparently they have their own custom time util

Comment: So it's not https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/TimeUtil.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** you are using protocol buffers' [`TimeUtil`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/TimeUtil.java#L226) you specify a duration with seconds separated from nanoseconds by a period. The value may be lead by a minus sign, if the duration is negative (so that adding the duration to a time would move into the past relative to the time). The string must end in "s".

You can see the pretty simple [parse](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/TimeUtil.java#L226) and [toString](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/e841bac4fcf47f809e089a70d5f84ac37b3883df/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/TimeUtil.java#L192) of a protocol buffer's duration in the public git[hub] repo's [`TimeUtil`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/TimeUtil.java).

Given the type of duration, I'm guessing they're used for calculations on  date-times that are internally represented as signed 64 bit nano seconds since unix epoch.

In other words it looks like these are valid durations:

```
"1s"      // one second forward
"1.0s"    // one second forward
"1.01s"   // one second, 10,000,000 nano seconds forward
"-1.01s"  // one second, 10,000,000 nano seconds backward
"60s"     // one minute forward
"-86400s" // yesterday (one day backward)
          // [assuming no daylight saving changes or leap seconds happened]
```

The Protocol Buffers' `TimeUtil.parseDuration` would not give you the error message you say you got, and is not at all like `Duration.parse`, which is [more clearly documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) and might give that kind of error message.

Comment: Can you explain the last sentence a little bit more?

Comment: What I could understand is they use iso durartion format like P1Y2M10DT2H30M which I do not understand it, do you think the duration that I provided as a text does not match with it?

Comment: @HamedMinaee I've linked to the parseDuration and toString functions for protocol buffers so you can see what those functions are doing and expect. I hope that's the best explanation of how a duration is positive or negative.

Answer (score 1):

**If guessed API:**

`parseDuration(String duration)` takes as parameters:

> duration - "3h" or "2mn" or "7s" or null.

Taken from `java.lang.Object ninja.utils.TimeUtil` API. It returns the number of seconds.

Then `"1.0:00:00"` is obviously not to be parsed.